# How to compare litere with an array of char with "("

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have problem to compare litere with an array of char with "(". I need a function to compare each array element with sign, but i don't know how to do it? Please help me.

```
   #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int v( const string &p )

{
    int lvl=0;
    int indeks=-1;
for(int i=0;i<=p.size();i++)
    {
    if(p[i]=="(")
        lvl--;
    //  else if(p[i]=="}")
    //  lvl++;
    //  else if(p[i]=="+")
        //indeks=i;
        //cout<<p[i]<<'\n';
    }
    //cout<<lvl;




}

int main()
{
    //string j; 
    string p;

    cin>>p;

    v(p);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: BTW, *liter* is a measurement of volume.  The word *letter* is what you are looking for (or *character*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare with `'('`.

Single quote `''` is used for character.

Double quote `""` is used for strings.